# IF determinant of a matrix is zero, then its rows are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a square matrix $A$ of size $n$. Let $R_1,...,R_n$ be its rows. I want to know an elementary proof of:

$$ |A| = 0 \iff R_1,...,R_n \; \; \; \text{are linearly dependent} $$

I mean, I know the proof for $n=3$. In fact, since $|A| = R_1 \cdot (R_2 \times R_3)$ and this equals zero, then this means that the vectors lie in the same plane, thus they are linearly dependent. However, how can we prove the result for the n case?

Comment: I think you meant _dependent_ in your title.

Comment: Are you allowed to use row operations? If you know how row operations affect the value of determinant, the proof shall be very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proof without linear maps:

Let $B$ be a square matrix with entries in the field $F.$

Recall that $\det(B)$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $B$ in an algebraic closure of $F.$

Hence, if $\det(B)=0,$ then $0$ must be an eigenvalue of $B.$

Hence there exists some non-zero vector $v$ such that $Bv=\mathbf{0}.$

This gives a non-trivial linear relation between the columns of $B.$

Now apply this argument with $B=A^T$ using the fact that $\det(A)=\det(A^T).$